# Webhook for docusign

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks, docusignconnect

My webhook url is not triggered when I received an envelope .I mean to say .I have created a developer account and created an app, then through connect I have set my webhook url..This webhook url is triggered when I am sending an envelope or some action performed by the receiver such as completed. But the webhook url is not triggered when an envelope is received in my inbox from other accounts. So I need to know is there anything extra I have to do in setting. If no please guide me How I can achieve this

For information::I am developing the application using node js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a webhook notification when you or another user on your account receives an envelope, you need to set up [Recipient Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/recipient-connect/). It is different from a standard Connect configuration which only works on envelopes that are sent out from your account.